# (iOS)How to implement Twitter Login through twitter app (not webview)

Tags: ios, swift, twitter-oauth

Here is a similar question I found in Twitter forums:
https://twittercommunity.com/t/ios-correct-url-for-in-app-authorization/136697/7

can we login with twitter without web view now?
I can see some apps in App Store implemented that function.(like [feather lite])
But no document shows how to do that.

Please Help!

Comment: Did you checked [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tutorials/step-by-step-guide-to-making-your-first-request-to-the-twitter-api-v2) ?

Comment: Looks like a guide for how to use v2 api. I read [this](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-2-0), and there is an authorize url in that document, but no scheme.